# HTML isn't rendering, HTML tags are being printed

Tags: views, 8, theming

I added a view template `views-view-fields--nieuws--page.html.twig` to my theme.

The template is correct, when I edit it I see the results on my website.

```
{% for field in fields %}
  {{ field.separator }}
  {{ field.wrapper_prefix }}
    {{ field.label_html }}
    {{ field.content }}
  {{ field.wrapper_suffix }}
{% endfor %}
```

In `page.html.twig` I print the region like this:

```
{{ page.content }}
```

But my output has HTML tags in it, any idea how I can solve this?

EDIT: It appears my HTML is rendering at all through Twig

```
{% set hello = '<strong>Hello</strong>' %}
{{ hello }}
```

outputs the `<strong>` tags, too.

Comment: raw filter: marks a variable as being safe. You try use `{{ hello | raw }}`.

Answer (score 2):

This is currently a known bug with the views-view-fields.html.twig template: https://www.drupal.org/node/2363423

Answer (score 2):

None of the above solution worked in my case. Here how I solved it by coding

```
function mytheme_preprocess_views_view_field(&$variables) {
  if ($variables['view']->id() == 'my_viewname' && $variables['field']->field == 'field_description') {
    $output = $variables['field']->getValue($variables['row']);
    $variables['output'] = ['#markup'=> $output];
  }
}
```

In views-view-fields--my-viewname.html.twig just print the value. No need to autoscaping or raw filer

```
{{ fields.field_description.content }}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to unescape HTML. There are two working ways to accomplish this.
First you can mark your field as "raw" and the html would render correctly. 
`{{ your_field | raw }}` should render ok.

As a second resort you can use twig's autoescape functionality:

```
{% autoescape false %}
{{ your_field }}
{% endautoescape %}
```

By this way you are telling twig not to escape html markup.

Answer (score -2):

You need to add `|raw` for print html  `{{ field.content|raw }}`  but you need to remove wrapper

```
{{ field.wrapper_prefix }} {{ field.wrapper_suffix }}
```